# How do you set symbol search scope in PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

How can I have the "navigate to symbol search box" only search within the current file?

Currently if I perform a search, it searches the entire project.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate | File Structure (Ctrl+F12).